# Create trigger to affect specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I want it to do is upon any insert of new rows or edit of existing rows on B, specific the 'last_seen' column would be updated on A.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_records
AFTER UPDATE ON loan_records
FOR EACH ROW
Update  temp_card A
INNER JOIN loan_records B
SET A.last_seen = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE A.card_no = B.card_no
```

and this

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_records2
AFTER INSERT ON loan_records
FOR EACH ROW
Update  temp_card A
INNER JOIN loan_records B
SET A.last_seen =CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE A.card_no = B.card_no
```

currently this updates all 'last_seen' columns in A, regardless whether or not they've been updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to `JOIN` both tables. Just use `NEW.card_no` in `WHERE` clause of your UPDATE statement.

Here is how both (`AFTER INSERT` and `AFTER UPDATE`) your triggers might look like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_loan_records_insert
AFTER INSERT ON loan_records
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE temp_card 
     SET last_seen = NOW()
   WHERE card_no = NEW.card_no;

CREATE TRIGGER tg_loan_records_update
AFTER UPDATE ON loan_records
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE temp_card 
     SET last_seen = NOW()
   WHERE card_no = NEW.card_no;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aac5c/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

you should refer to only currently updated id.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_records2
AFTER INSERT ON loan_records
FOR EACH ROW
Update  temp_card A
INNER JOIN loan_records B
SET A.last_seen =CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE A.card_no = B.card_no and a.id = OLD.id
```

For more details on how to use for before update, after update please refer

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html